# React JS - Props is not shown in the rendered HTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I created a react component and passing props to it. But when the control is rendered, I do not see the prop and its value. Due to this I am getting error.

This is how I am calling the component, passing `key2` as a prop:

```
 return <Card className="card" key2={uuidv4()}>{items}</Card>;
```

This is how the component looks:

```
import "./Card.css";
function Card(props) {
  const classes = "card " + props.className;
console.log("key:" + props.key2)
  return (
    <div key={props.key2} className={classes}>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Card;
```

This is how the **div** was rednderd

```
<div class="card card"></div>
```

**Expected:**

```
<div class="card card" key="6bbf4919-3e38-40f0-8687-910feffcf3f6"></div>
```

See below screenshot for more info:

[image]

Comment: Have deleted my answer but it turns out OP is just trying to solve an _"Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."_ error. Probably in whatever they're passing to `<Card>` as `children`